# Displaying images within ReactJS Card

Tags: html, css, reactjs, web, styled-components

I am working on a project which will feature a leaderboard with player icons, name and scores.

[Here is my initial design that im trying to implement.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9koRi.png)

Im using cards to hold each element and will eventually will be inserting data from my DB, however rn I'm just trying to get the design skeleton together all smooth. I can get the text working and aligned fine but cant figure out how to it with text. Before I was just using the cards for text and the images as its own element, [it worked fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l2je.png) til I [tried to put more than one row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLFqo.png).

Now when I'm trying to put the image in as a card, it's just [printing info about the image instead of the actual image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsVEY.png)  I'm quite new to React so sorry if its a simple solution. I've been playing with this all day and cant find a solution that works for me.

Heres the code so far! Thanks so much for taking the time to read and any advice is greatly appreciated!

**Index.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import dogicon from './assets/doggo.png'
import './index.css';

export const Grid = styled.div`

`;

export const Row = styled.div`

    display: flex;
    background-color: #c3b0d3;
    display: block ruby;
`;

export const Col = styled.div`
    flex: ${(props) => props.size};
`;

const CardStyle = styled.div`
    
    display: block ruby;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
`;

console.log(dogicon);

const LeaderboardHeader = () => {
  return (
    <div className="leadheader">
        <h2>LEADERBOARD</h2>
    </div>
  )
}

class Card extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <p>{this.props.name}</p> <p>{this.props.score}</p> <p>{this.props.icon}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {

    // fires before component is mounted
    constructor(props) {
        
        // makes this refer to this component
        super(props);

        // set local state
        this.state = {
            name: "PLAYER 1",
            score: "200",
            icon: require('./assets/doggo.png'),
        };

    }

    render() {
      const {name} = this.state; 
      const{score} = this.state;
      const{icon} = this.state;
      return (
        <div className="container">  

          <LeaderboardHeader />

            <Grid>
                <Row>
                <CardStyle>
                    <Col size={1}>
                        <Card icon={icon}/>
                    </Col>
                </CardStyle>
                <CardStyle>     
                    <Col size={1}>
                        <Card name ={name} />
                        <Card name ={name} />
                        <Card name ={name} />
                    </Col>
                </CardStyle>
                <CardStyle> 
                    <Col size={1}>
                        <Card score={score} />
                        <Card score={score} />
                        <Card score={score} />
                    </Col>
                    </CardStyle>
                </Row>
            </Grid>
        </div>
      )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Index.css**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Passion+One&display=swap');


body {
  font: 50px;
  font-family: 'Passion One', cursive;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #7E549F;  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.container{
    width: 550px;
}

.leadheader {
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: #422D53;
  color: #C3B0D3;
  text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.card {
  background-color: #C3B0D3;
  color: #2A1D34;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 100px 0;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use that image data in the `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag. Since you are using `<p>{this.props.icon}</p>` it is coerced to string, hence displaying the text value of the image.

So, this would be the final result:

```
class Card extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <p>{this.props.name}</p> <p>{this.props.score}</p> <img src={this.props.icon} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: got it!! thank u so much, just need to style it now :D